# Sequencing element collapse and content reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a site where the main content is displayed in a `div` centered in the page. The `div` is animated to expand from nothing upon opening, with content loaded from a PHP file. When a user clicks a different menu selection, the `div` is meant to clear out the current content, collapse back to nothing, and then expand again with new content.

Everything seems to be working except for the clearing out part (the expand/collapse and new data loading are functional.) The problem is that the new data loads immediately when clicking on a different site section - what I want it to do is blank out while collapsing, and thus the new content should appear only upon the re-expansion of the `div`. This is the code snippet that is giving me trouble:

JQuery code:

```
//OPENS DIV
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#content').show('scale', 1000);
});

//LOADS CONTENT FROM PHP FILE INTO DIV
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#content').load('../register.php');
});


//SUPPOSED TO CLEAR OUT DIV, COLLAPSE IT, AND RE-EXPAND IT WITH NEW CONTENT
$('#option').click(function() {
  $('#content').html('').hide('scale', 500);
  $('#content').show('scale', 1000).load('../addroom.php');
});
```

Comment: the load method should reference a path *relative to the home page* - as opposed to relative to the script file.  Did you try that?

Comment: try put functions to queue using .when(), first reset your content and second load file

Comment: @ochi Yeah just tried that, no dice. Path doesn't seem to be the issue, everything loads, it's just that the new file/div loads too quickly. It loads immediately when the menu option is clicked, whereas I want the div to go blank (or even just do nothing) before/while collapsing, and I want the new content to not show up until the div expands (or starts expanding) again.

Comment: @daremachine not sure I'm familiar with that one, can you give me an example please?

Comment: it provide a callback on call. Look at doc...its simple to understand https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: or you can try show content after load was success via callback. .load provide callback. Look at Callback Function http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: try first loading the content and then showing it... (using a callback as suggested) See docs: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 1):

First, you do not need multiple `$(document).ready(function(){...}));` statements, you can collapse them like below.

Also, if this page is index.php and your hierarchy is like this:

```
/parent directory
 -index.php
 -addroom.php
```

Then you could do

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // OPENS DIV
  $('#content').show('scale', 1000);

  //LOADS CONTENT FROM PHP FILE INTO DIV  
  $('#content').load('../register.php');

  //bind click to clear, hide, load and show div
  $('#option').click(function() {
    $('#content').html('').hide('scale', 500);

    // assuming that addroom.php is at the same level as this file/page
    $('#content').load('addroom.php', function() {
      $('#content').delay(2000).show('scale', 1000);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">content
</div>
<hr/>
<button id="option">load</button>
```

Comment: Hmm... I tried that snippet and it's giving me the same result, with the second file loading immediately, instead of upon expanding. I see what you mean though (re: multiple $(document).ready())

Comment: @Matt weird, try adding a small delay to see if it makes a difference... see updated code with `.delay(2000)`

Comment: yeah that's actually the first thing I tried, I must have tried a `.delay()` method in a dozen different places, most of which had the same effect (a couple of times it just delayed the `.show()` action but still loaded the internal div content immediately.)